# How to run Django new project in the same VS code folder which already has a project that is running on every runserver Port?

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, port, new-project

I created two projects baseproject and web_project using django in vs code folder: smcode5 with virtual environment.

I used web_project first to create an app and run on server port 8000.

Now I want to use baseproject for an app, but only web_project runs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: run other project on a different port. python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001

Comment: your command gives result: this site can't be reached.

Comment: However, this command works: python manage.py runserver 8001. But still only project 1 is running, project 2 isn't. Do I have to shift my project1? Does django server allow only one project to run at a time?

Comment: Could you share your project structure? How did you create the projects and app? And  the error output? More details is required.

Comment: I used an improved project structure and now I can use other ports. Thanks.